# How to get the direction for moving "sideways" in 3D space?

Tags: trigonometry, 3d

I am not entirely sure on how to phrase this question.

Imagine I have an object in 3D space. I got its position, the rotation and the direction it is facing each represented as a vector.

Now I want to move this object sideways, to the left and to the right.

How do I calculate the direction vector I have to move?

Comment: Is the direction it is facing not the direction vector it moves on?

Comment: it's not moving in the direction it is facing

Comment: What do you mean by left and right in 3D?

Comment: If you have vectors pointing in the object's "front" and "top" directions, then the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of those vectors will point "left" or "right" (depending upon the order of the vectors in the product).

Comment: if you look into your room, you know the direction you're facing and where you are in the room. Now what direction would you go if you take a step to the left while keeping the direction you're facing?

Comment: Given only you're looking "into" your room, you might not be *in* the room, so what would "where you are in the room" mean in that case?

Comment: just some random x, y and z coordinates

Comment: If you want to move "horizontally" relative to the floor of the room, you can take the cross product of the object's "facing" vector and the *room's* "up" vector. (If the object is facing straight up or down, then this gives the zero vector, indicating that the result is ambiguous.)

Comment: Attach a reference frame to your object, for example with $x$ axis pointing to the RIGHT, and the $y$ axis pointing FORWARD, and $z$ axis pointing UP, then to move side ways you have to move in the positive $x$ direction to move RIGHT, and the negative $x$ direction to move LEFT.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I try to explain it to the best of my abilities, however I am not great at maths.

1. create a plane using the normal vector (0,1,0)
2. set the quaternion (rotation) of the plane to the rotation of the object you want to move
3. get the new normal vector of the plane
4. finally calculate the cross vector of the new normal vector and the vector which represents the direction your object is facing.

I created a function which does exactly this using [threeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70053957/how-can-i-move-my-camera-sideways-in-threejs)

I would be happy for suggestions and it would be great if someone could format this answer properly, for I don't know how to write this properly.
Thank you guys for the help :)